# To append strings at the end of comma separated CSV file through Jenkins Job

Tags: shell, csv, jenkins, awk, sed

I have a comma-separated csv file on which I would like to perform below operation using a Jenkins job.

**My csv file is something like below**

```
String1,String2,123
String3,String4,456
String5,String6,789
```

So when the Jenkins job runs with the parameter **abc** it should get appended at the end of csv file as below.

```
String1,String2,123
String3,String4,456
String5,String6,789,abc|
```

Again when the same Jenkins job runs with different/same parameter(say **def** in this case) it should get appended at the end of csv file as below.

```
String1,String2,123
String3,String4,456
String5,String6,789,abc|def|
```

So everytime when the job runs with a parameter it should get appended at the end of CSV file as above with first paratmeter separated by a comma and the following parameter with the pipe.

So when the job runs third time with the parameter **ghi**, the csv file should look as below.

```
String1,String2,123
String3,String4,456
String5,String6,789,abc|def|ghi|
```

I am using Jenkins execute shell and abc,def,ghi is coming from job parameter (**$JOBNAME**).

I did try using

```
sed -i '$s/$/,'"$JOBNAME"'|/' file.csv
```

But it only works for the first time. When the job runs the second time instead of appending, it gets substituted and my csv file instead of looking like below

```
String1,String2,123
String3,String4,456
String5,String6,789,abc|def|
```

looks like

```
String1,String2,123
String3,String4,456
String5,String6,789,def|
```

I would like to know if we can do it using sed or any other command or combination of commands that the string keeps getting appended at the end of csv file each time the Jenkins job runs.

Comment: Is the number of fields in the csv file fixed?

Comment: Just working from the command line, this works fine for me as-is. Is it possible you are copying in the `file.csv` fresh from somewhere each time?

Comment: This does duplicate the commas though.  When you get your other issue sorted out, tweak your `sed`: `sed -i '${ /[0-9]$/s/$/,/; s/$/'"$JOBNAME"'|/; }' file.csv`

Comment: Someone named Nikhil Kumar asked this exact same question yesterday ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/63325308/1745001) but that was deleted 1 hour ago when this new question was opened. Why the name change and new question instead of following up on and responding to the questions and comments under your existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With single `awk` itself.

```
awk  -v jenkins_var="abc" '
prev!=""{
  print prev
}
{
  prev=$0
}
END{
  print prev"|"jenkins_var
}
' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Could you please try following `tac` + `awk` solution, written and tested with shown samples. Just change variable name `jenkins_var` with value which is coming during your jenkins run and this should keep appending value to last line of Input_file.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk -v jenkins_var="def" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  print $0"|"jenkins_var
  next
}
1
' | 
tac > temp && mv temp Input_file
```